# What title does Padmé Amidala have?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars

In the *Star Wars* prequels, Amidala is referred to by a few different titles which confused me a bit.

In The Phantom Menace, she is called "Queen Amidala" by many characters.

In The Attack of the Clones, she is "demoted" (it would seem) to "Senator Amidala" and she meets the current Naboo Queen, Jamailla (I think)

I've seen this issue mentioned before:

[image: Issue mentioned in YouTube movie-sins channel]

and, like the narrator in that, I was confused as well.

Does anyone know what the powers are in Naboo? Is there any canon evidence for this? It does say in the opening crawl from Attack of the Clones:

> Senator Amidala, the **former** Queen of Naboo

which would suggest that she abdicated as that is the only way (aside death) that a monarch can stop being the monarch.

Comment: A *lot* of historic kings (and queens) were elected, bloodline is not the only mode. I don't know about the politics of a galaxy far, far away, but the critic misses the point.

Comment: I seem to recall it is mentioned in The Phantom Menace that she is elected Queen.  The starwars wiki pages indicate she serves 2-terms - but I don't know if that is canon or not.  Her election to the Republic Senate is an entirely separate political role of an entirely different political body and not a 'demotion' or 'promotion'.

Comment: She goes from Queen of a single planet to Senator representing that planet in the government of the entire galaxy. It would be similar to going from the Mayor of a city to being a senator or member of parliament in the national government.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Naboo doesn't have a kingship like we are used to, where kings/queens are bloodline royalty for life (or exile, natch). A preteen/teen is elected "Queen" (or King), and gives up the throne after some years. Two terms max, constitutionally limited.

She then was appointed Senator, a completely mutually exclusive event.

Naboo's system works more like modern day US presidential system. The title of "Queen" simply confuses things for us/the audience.

Comment: Can you back this information up a little somehow?

Comment: I don't think (though I may very well be wrong) that there's any evidence that its definitely 'mutually exclusive' ... she was Senator after she left the office of Queen and these are certainly independent political offices, but I don't think its actually said anywhere that she couldn't hold both offices at the same time.  I'd suggest changing to something like 'a completely separate role in a different political system'

Comment: @iandotkelly mutually exclusive **events**, in that her becoming a senator didn't have anything directly to do with her having been a queen. And they likely are mutually exclusive offices, as the new Queen appointed Padme the senator. The duties of each role would make one person having both roles very difficult.

Comment: "Mutually exclusive" implies one cannot happen at the same time or concurrent with the other, even if not intended by you; independent, unconnected are all words that would convey the situation more accurately imho.  I agree - they are very likely to be exclusive offices, whether by law or by practicality - I'm just saying that I think you're conveying a situation that is not necessarily backed up by the movies.

Comment: This is an old question, but the entire thing is spelled out in the new book _Queen's Shadow_ which was released March 5, 2019.